# Explicit expression of automorphic representations as automorphic forms

Tags: nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, automorphic-forms, eisenstein-series

Let‘s take $G=GL_n$ over a number field $F$ for example.

It's already known that every irreducible automorphic representation $\pi$ is a irreducible component of a induced representation $I(G,P;\sigma_1,\cdots,\sigma_r)$, where $P$ is the standard parabolic subgroup of $G$ with respect to a partition $n=n_1+\cdots+n_r$, and $\sigma_i$ is a cuspidal automorphic representation of $GL_{n_i}$. (The reference is *Automorphic forms and automorphic representations* by Borel and Jacquet in "Corvallis" Part 1).

As an application, one can define principal $L$- functions for a not-necessarily-cuspidal automorphic representation. (The references are *Principal $L$- functions for the linear group* by Jacquet in "Corvallis" Part 2, and chap 13 of the book [The Genesis of the Langlands Program](https://doi.org/10.1017/9781108591218)) However, it seems that the progress is done all in the language of representations.

My question is that, could we express elements in $\pi$ as automorphic forms, i.e. functions on $G(\mathbb{A})$?

More explicitly, given $\sigma$ as above, should we consider the space spaned by the Eisenstein series $E(\phi,\lambda)$, where $\phi$ in $\sigma$ and $\lambda$ fixed? And what's the relation between that space and the Langlands quotient with respect to $\sigma$ ?

Comment: I am not quite sure whether this answers your question. The construction of the induced representations says that each is given by certain sections of a vector bundle. This bundle also has distibution-valued sections. In Gelfand et al: Generalized functions Vol 6 you find that the $\Gamma$-invariant vectors of this space give the $\Gamma$-automorphic embeddings, where $\Gamma$ is an arithmetic group.